# Android application performance monitoring tool

Tags: android, performance, analytics, monitoring

I have developed an Android game app, and now I am looking for a tool that would monitor my apps real user performance (like CPU, memory, GPU, network, latency, etc.).

I know about NewRelic's mobile APN monitoring, but it is too expensive for me.

What would be other options?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are simply looking to understand the consumption of each of the device vitals by your application, then there are several tools on the Google Play which will help you with the same. Some of them may include **CPU Monitor, 3C Toolbox, Elixir 2 etc**.

Not to mention Android Studio's inbuilt monitoring capability.

**Reference link :** https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/index.html

---

However, if you are looking to monitor on the production and understand the real user experience, then you will have to invest some cash. But there are free tools such as **Fabric** which would provide device vitals during crashes in the production. Along with the device vitals there are several other details such as stack trace, time of crash, geography etc. that would be available on Fabric.

You could also try **Apteligent**, yet another mobile front end performance monitoring solution, to monitor your application in the production. This is similar to Fabric but provides more in depth information about crashes (in addition to device vitals) and slow transactions. However, this is a commercial tool but comes with free trial (limited features). Though I am not sure of the pricing and licensing models provided by them, they are as efficient as New Relic, Appdynamics, Dynatrace and such from a mobile front end perspective.

You can also refer to this post that I came across if that helps : https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/13936/measure-resource-intensive-actions-in-a-mobile-application/18880#18880