# Website load testing on a mobile device

Tags: performance

I am trying to test web page performance on a mobile device. I know chrome dev tools can be used for mobile simulation but my requirement is that it should be tested on actual device. Is there any such tool available?

Comment: Yes, there are such services available that uses simulated or actual devices. You can find them by doing a web search for "cross browser testing".

Comment: i am assuming you are wanting to know the real user experience on the actual device but not use real devices to performance test the web application itself. In such a case, you can refer to this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37363076/android-application-performance-monitoring-tool/37500031#37500031

Comment: and possibly your question might be put on hold as asking for tool suggestions might be a very wide topic and might give biased responses. kindly rephrase your question so that it narrows down to a specific problem like why you would like to go for real devices rather than use the chrome's emulators or if you have got a particular issue in place because of using them or something on similar lines.. just a suggestion

Comment: See concept, GUI Virtual User vs API level Virtual User.  Also, you should be asking the question early and often for a single user widget, component or user level test, have we met performance for a single ______?  For, if it is not performant for one, it can never be performant for many.....

Answer (score 1):

I am little confused about your question since in the title you mentioned load testing, but in the detail load testing is not mentioned at all. So, I'll try to answer both:

You can test mobile via emulation or real devices.
If it is necessary to use real devices you can do it in two general ways:

1. On premise tools such an Experitest.
2. Using a cloud service like Perfecto Mobile, mobilelabsinc, amazon aws device farm.

You can test your application performance with these tools without any relation to load. That is, how fast they work on your device.

If you want to test your application performance and see its behavior on the device while loading your server then you need to add a load testing tool into your test.  For example, HP/LoadRunner, RadView/WebLOAD has integration with Perfecto Mobile. I heard also that JMeter has an integration well – not sure.

In any case, during the load, the recommendation is that the majority of the back end server load will be created via mobile simulation, and add only a few real mobile devices to the party in order to measure the performance from the device itself – because using real devices will be expensive.

Full disclosure: I work for Radview.

Answer (score 0):

SOASTA CloudTest also supports the integration of API/Transport level virtual users with on-device virtual users in the same scenario